# asp.net Gridview

Tags: asp.net

Una duda, como puedo hacer, para que cuando le haga un zoom al navegador el gridview aun siga ocupando todo el ancho de la pantalla.

Actualmente hago zoom de 45% como en la imagen, y se ve hace mas chico el gridview y yo busco que aun siga ocupando todo el ancho de pantalla..

Este es el codigo tras el grid.

````
          <asp:GridView ID="grdPDFView" runat="server" Width="100%" AllowPaging="false" ColumnAutoWidth="false" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table table-responsive" 
                DataKeyNames="ID,Clave" OnDataBound="OnDataBound" 
                ondatabinding="grdPDFView_DataBinding" Visible="False" 
                onrowdeleting="grdPDFView_RowDeleting"
                onrowcommand="grdPDFView_RowCommand" onrowdatabound="grdPDFView_RowDataBound" 
                onrowcancelingedit="grdPDFView_RowCancelingEdit" 
                onrowediting="grdPDFView_RowEditing" 
                onrowupdating="grdPDFView_RowUpdating">
            <Columns>
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#"  HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Justify">
                        <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" disabled="disabled" OnClientClick="return false;" runat="server" href='<%# string.Format("http://localhost:58701/RevisionMotoresEmis.aspx?Clave={0}",Eval("Clave")) %>' Text='<%# Eval("ID", "{0}") %>'></asp:LinkButton>

        <%-- <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton5" runat="server" OnClientClick="showProgress();" href='<%# string.Format("http://amrnmcvpwi02/ControlDocumentos/RevisionMotoresEmis.aspx?Clave={0}",Eval("Clave")) %>' Text='<%# Eval("ID", "{0}") %>'></asp:LinkButton>--%>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                       <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
                       <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Justify"></ItemStyle>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Clave&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Justify">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                      
                             <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" OnClientClick="openInNewTab();" OnClick="OpenDocument" Text='<%# Eval("Clave") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                             <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtoLink10emis" runat="server" href='<%#Eval("Link")%>' Text='<%#Eval("Clave")%>' Target="_blank"></asp:LinkButton>
                            </ItemTemplate> <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
                     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Justify"></ItemStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="DescripcionArchivo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Título&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"  SortExpression="DescripcionArchivo"  />
                   <asp:BoundField DataField="Revision" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Revisión" SortExpression="Revision" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="FechaRevision" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Fecha&nbsp;revisión" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="FechaRevision" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="RevisadoPor" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Revisado&nbsp;por&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" SortExpression="RevisadoPor" />
                 
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="AprobadoPor" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Aprobado&nbsp;por" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="AprobadoPor" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Area1" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Área1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" SortExpression="Area1" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Area2" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Área2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Area3" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Área3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" SortExpression="Area3" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                  <asp:BoundField DataField="Area4" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Área4&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="TipodeInstruccion" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Tipo de instrucción" SortExpression="TipodeInstruccion" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="FrameMaquinaCell" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Frame máquina /cell"  SortExpression="FrameMaquinaCell" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  />
           </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>

 
          ```



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF6bO.jpg
````

Comment: Has intentado modificarlo por css? algo como `.screenWidth {width:100vw;}` y usas esa clase en tu CssClass

Comment: Lo probe Abraham. Pero sigue igual.. Cabe aclarar que estoy usando el plugin gridviewScroll para mantener estaticos el encabezado del gridview. Y utilizo este java script  $(document).ready(function () {
         gridviewScroll();
     });

     function gridviewScroll() {
         $('#<%=grdPDFView.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({

             width:100%,
             height: "500",
             barhovercolor: "#C8C8C8",
             barcolor: "#C8C8C8"
         });
     }  le agrego el width:100% pero me marca error no me reconoce el signo de porcentaje..

Comment: Si no te reconoce el porcentaje, puedes asignarlo por variable en js, `gridviewScroll() { var swidth=$(window).width(); $('#<%=grdPDFView.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({ width:swidth, ...`

Comment: La verdad muchas gracias por tu tiempo Abraham. Pero no funciona, cuando hago el zoom mas pequeño.. se muestra como en la imagen que adjunte..Seguiré buscando la forma. Cualquier asesoría es bienvenida..

Comment: quizá solo falta volver a dibujar la tabla cuando se detecte el zoom, no se si funcione puedo puedes probar `$(window).resize(function(){gridviewScroll();})`

Comment: Igual vi que acabo de notas es que en tu parámetro `width:100%` le faltan las comillas `width:"100%"` pero una vez dibujado tendría que reaccionar al resize

Comment: Hola Abraham. En que parte podria poner lo de resize.. Le se algo al javascript. Pero no es mi fuerte.. Asi tal cual lo escribes?.. La verdad me rendi, mañana le sigo y comento por aquí si funciono. Y otra vez gracias..

Comment: Si, así tal cual, solo debe de ser capaz de llamar a tu función, si quieres puedes ponerlo después del `$(document).ready(function () { gridviewScroll(); }); $(window).resize(function(){gridviewScroll();});`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Mañana por la mañana lo pruebo.. Y comento como me fue..muchas gracias...

Comment: Si reacciona lo del resize. Te agradezco mucho Abraham, por si a alguien mas le sirve así me quedo.  $(document).ready(function () {
           gridviewScroll();
       });

       $(window).resize(function () {
           gridviewScroll();
       });
       function gridviewScroll() {
           var swidth = $(window).width();
           $('#<%=grdPDFView.ClientID%>').gridviewScroll({

               width: swidth,
               height: 700,
               barhovercolor: "#C8C8C8",
               barcolor: "#C8C8C8"
           });
       }